# Why do I get the error, "Extra argument: students" in my code

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title of my question and I don't know why or how to resolve it? Beginning Swift hobbyist here so please explain in understandable terms. Thank you very much.

```
struct Student {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let grade: String
}

struct Classroom {
    let nameOfClass: String
    let students: [Student] = []
}

let student1 = Student(firstName: "Keith", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "F")
let class1 = Classroom(nameOfClass: "Swift", students: student1)
```

My ultimate goal is to fill an array of students of type Student, which in and of itself is confusing me, but I'm just trying to get over this first hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to git rid of `= []`

```
 struct Classroom {
    let nameOfClass: String
    let students: [Student]

 }
```

---

```
let student1 = Student(firstName: "Keith", lastName: "Grimes", grade: "F")
let class1 = Classroom(nameOfClass: "Swift", students: [student1])
```

---

Discussion:

When you add a default value for a property inside your struct , it doesn't consider it in it's automatic `init` method , plus you declare `students` as an array and send a single object of type `Student` so wrap it inside `[]` , if you need to have both you can add another init like below

```
struct Classroom {
    var nameOfClass: String
    var students: [Student] = []

    init(nameOfClass:String,students:[Student] = []) {
        self.nameOfClass = nameOfClass
        self.students = students
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

students is an array of Student aka [Student] therefore you need to pass [student1] or change let students to Student